# How to write unit test for service having dependency on other service or database

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, integration-testing, moq

Sorry if I am asking very basic question,

I have set of web services (developed using .Net WebApi). These services are either business layer or data access layer APIs.  These APIs are either dependent on other services or database itself.

I want to write unit test cases for it. I have following questions

1. As business layer APIs has dependency on data access service or some other service. If I write unit test just to invoke business API then it would invoke data access API. Is this the correct way to write unit test case? or should I inject all dependency object with unit test? I think earlier one would be integration test not unit test.
2. Should I write unit tests for Data access layer at all? I checked this link ([Writing tests for data access code: Unit tests are waste](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/writing-tests-for-data-access-code-unit-tests-are-waste/)) and it says DAL does not require unit tests. Should I still write tests for data access layer. I think it would be integration test not unit tests?

Comment: For 2, I think it depends on how much business logic is in your DAL. If there's testable logic, it stands to reason unit tests can help make the code reliable. If the DAL is just doing simple CRUD operations, I don't think it makes sense to UT. For 1, best practices suggest all your services should implement interfaces. If UI -> Business -> DAL, you might have IBusiness and IDAL, making each interface testable through UT mocks and fakes.

Comment: I think people get way too caught up in terminology in a desire to sound "right" or "smart." Having tests that will prevent regression is a *good thing*. Whether those tests touch a database or don't touch a database really doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things. Having tests == good, not having tests == bad. Having said that, if you want pure unit tests you should inject all dependencies with faked implementations. I like FakeItEasy but there are other frameworks that will help you do that. If your DAL performs logic beyond reading and returning data you should test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1:

I would say if you want to do TDD, then it's not the "correct" way, because as you said, you would be performing integration tests. Then again, maybe you *don't* want to do TDD and integration tests are good enough for you, but to answer the question: this wouldn't be the proper way to **unit-**test your code.

---

### Question 2

I would say it depends what you have in your data access layer. For instance, if you implement repositories, you will probably want to write a few tests.

#### Save method

You want to make sure that given an entity that you have retrieved from your repository, editing some properties of this entity and persisting the changes will actually save the modifications and not create a new entity. Now: you might think this is an integration test, but it really depends on how well designed your code is. For instance, your repository could be just an extra layer of logic on top of a low-level ORM. In that case, when testing the save method, what you will do is that you will assert that the right methods are called with the right parameters on the ORM service injected in your repository.

#### Errors and exceptions

While accessing data, it is possible to have problems such as connection to the database being broken, or that the format of the data is not as expected, or deserialization problems. If you want to provide some good error handling and perhaps create custom exceptions and add more information to them depending on the context, then you definitely want to write tests to make sure the corrext information is propagated

**on the other hand**

If your DAL is just a few classes that wrap a non-mockable ORM, and you don't have any logic in there, then perhaps you don't need tests, but it seems that this doesn't happen too often, you will pretty much always have a bit of logic that can go wrong and that you want to test.